# Send Data Via Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I have an `TableView` and I want to transfer Data with the prepare(for segue) method to a different ViewController, but I want to use the delegate method for learning purposes. I did this:

```
protocol SendName {
    func send(name: String)
}

class ContactsTVC: UITableViewController, GetData {

    var delegate: SendName?
    var contacts = ["Anja Deo","Hans Peter","Müller Schmitz"] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Kontakte"
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showContactDetailView" {
            let destination = segue.destination as! ContactDetailViewVC
            if let delegate = delegate  {
                let selectedContact = contacts[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row)]
                 delegate.send(name: selectedContact)
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Of course all of this in the UITableViewController class.

and in the ViewController I want to go to I did this:

```
class ContactDetailViewVC: UIViewController, SendName {

    var selectedContact: ContactsTVC?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    selectedContact?.delegate = self

    }

    func send(name: String) {
        self.title = name
        print("Should work")
    }
}
```

Comment: I read many tutorials, but they are just show how to transfert from b to a not from a to b its different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a place for a delegate to be used like you did in `prepare` method, once you get `let destination = segue.destination as! ContactDetailViewVC` you know it is of type `ContactDetailViewVC` and compiler knows that `ContactDetailViewVC` conforms to `SendName` protocol so you can just invoke send method on the `destination` with `destination.send(name: selectedContact)`

Your method would thus change to:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ContactDetailViewVC {
        let selectedContact = contacts[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row)]
        destination.send(name: selectedContact)
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that this works but I want to try with delegates. I´m in the learning phase

Comment: You are trying to use a delegate for a thing that delegates are not used for...If you want to learn how to use a delegate check the following: https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: Or this one: https://blog.bobthedeveloper.io/the-meaning-of-delegate-in-swift-347eaa9674d

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the value of `var delegate: SendName?` in ContactsTVC itself. Delegates should be weak to avoid retain cycle, `weak var delegate: SendName?`.

Comment: still the same issue

Comment: How did you set the value of delegate variable?

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `delegate` object directly to call send function.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showContactDetailView" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ContactDetailViewVC
        delegate.send(name: contacts[(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row)])
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same.

Comment: There's no error. It just don't work. The function send does not execute in the ContactDetailViewVC